# How do you use C++/CX and include Windows Runtime Libraries in a console application?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I would like to be able to access the Windows namespace (e.g. Windows::Storage::Compression, Windows::Web::Json) from a console application. I am currently using a Win32 Console Application Project.

Comment: You cannot target console mode apps in WinRT, only Store apps that run in a sandbox.  The console api is not permitted by that sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

Reference metadata [winmd file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh708954.aspx) referenced in the API's documentation in your desktop console application. You can then use APIs that are marked as DualApiPartition, such as [Windows::Storage::Compression::Compressor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.compression.compressor.aspx). Note in the desktop projects the Core tab doesn’t appear by default. See [msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh708954(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh708954%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for steps to enable a metadata reference to appear in the add reference dialog.

In earlier version of Visual Studio, you can call the same class via COM, if you have Windows 8 Kit installed.

Comment: I can't find any way to reference winmd files. The reference manager offers me no options nor does it allow me to browse the file system.

Comment: In the desktop projects the Core tab doesn’t appear by default. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh708954(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The MSDN resource provided, have a Core Subgroup subtitle look for it and it will give you the way you can call WinRT from a console app.

Comment: Or if you're too lazy, this article explains how to do it: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToCallWinRTAPIsInWindows8FromCDesktopApplicationsWinRTDiagram.aspx